# Changing BackgroundColor with Javascript included video sequence animation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, addeventlistener

Im trying to Highlight the subtitles of the Videos in JS.
The video sequence are working totally fine, but the Subtitle not getting highlighted.

The idea behind is:

If video1 is starting, then the subtitle of video1 got highlighted at same time

after this

If video2 is starting, then the subtitle of video2 got highlighted at same time
...

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">
                    <div class="flex-item">
                        <video id="video1" poster="/assets/vids1/1.png" muted autoplay>
                            <source src="/assets/vids1/1.webm" type="video/webm" />
                        </video>
                        <h1 id="dcka">TEST</h1>
                    </div>
        
                    <div class="flex-item">
                        <video id="video2" poster="/assets/vids1/2.png" muted >
                            <source src="/assets/vids1/2.webm" type="video/webm" />
                        </video>
                                        
                    </div>
        
                    <div class="flex-item">
                        <video id="video3" poster="/assets/vids1/3.png" muted >
                            <source src="/assets/vids1/3.webm" type="video/webm" />
                        </video>
                                         
                    </div>
        
                    <div class="flex-item">
                        <video id="video4" poster="/assets/vids1/4.png" muted >
                            <source src="/assets/vids1/4.webm" type="video/webm" />
                        </video>
                                        
                    </div>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function()
         { 
            //now that the window has loaded we add our event listeners to the videos.
            //When video1 has ended, play video2 etc
                document.getElementById("video1").addEventListener("ended", function()
                {
                    playVideo("video2");     
                    
                    // title
                    var el = document.getElementById('dcka');
                    setColor(el, 'green')
                });
     
                document.getElementById("video2").addEventListener("ended", function()
                {
                    playVideo("video3"); 
                });
     
                document.getElementById("video3").addEventListener("ended", function()
                { 
                    playVideo("video4"); 
                });          
          }

        function playVideo(videoID)
        {
            //This playVideo function takes in the ID of a video element and plays that video.         
            var videoElement = document.getElementById(videoID);
            videoElement.play();
        }

        function setColor(element, color)
        {
            element.style.backgroundColor = color;
        }
```

Thanks for helping :)

**EDIT pythonmaxi (WORKING):**

```
 window.onload = function()
         { 
            //now that the window has loaded we add our event listeners to the videos.
            //When video1 has ended, play video2 etc
                const dcka = document.getElementById('dcka');
     
                 document.getElementById("video1").addEventListener("play", function()
                 {
                    setColor(dcka, "darkgreen");
                 });

                document.getElementById("video1").addEventListener("ended", function()
                {
                    playVideo("video2");     
                });
     
                document.getElementById("video2").addEventListener("ended", function()
                {
                    playVideo("video3"); 
                });
     
                document.getElementById("video3").addEventListener("ended", function()
                { 
                    playVideo("video4"); 
                });          
          }

        function playVideo(videoID)
        {
            //This playVideo function takes in the ID of a video element and plays that video.         
            var videoElement = document.getElementById(videoID);
            videoElement.play();
        }

        function setColor(element, color)
        {
            element.style.backgroundColor = color;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if I got this right, you want to change the `background-color` of `#dcka` when `video1` starts?

In that case, you would want to add a `play` event listener that would call `setColor(dckael, whatevercolor)`:

```js
const dcka = document.getElementById('dcka');

document.getElementById("video1").addEventListener("play", function() {
    setColor(dcka, "darkgreen" /* what ever color you want */ );
});
```

Comment: "Im not sure if I got this right, you want to change the background-color of #dcka when video1 starts?" - Yes

Comment: Oops, I was calling setColor on the video, try again with `dcka`

Comment: I did it, look at "EDIT pythonmaxi", but its still not working, maybe I´m still doing something wrong or missunderstood. Can you please check? Thanks :)

Comment: Found the mistake.
After many tests i realized, that the **#id** has to be **unique**.
I had 4 same Ids, the addEventListener could not get the unique #id.
Now i gave 4 different ID`s and its working perfect! my mistake!

 @pythonmaxi thanks for your work, working finally!